# Pass PHPExcel object in form post

Tags: php, phpexcel

Is it possible to pass a PHP `phpexcel` object into a page's HTML so I can pass it back to the server with a form `POST` or in an ajax call using jquery or something? I create the object when I'm generating an html table view of the data and I want them to be able to click on a button and download it as a document if they want it, but I want to be able to use the object I already created to produce the download document for them.

Can I pass the object to the client in the HTML and then pass it back to the server?

Comment: I am not sure I follow 100% but can you not serialize the resulting data as JSON and pass to jQuery that way?

Comment: Is it possible to serialize a PHPExcel?

Comment: You can serialize the native object, yes. If it uses or keeps the data in an excel extension or something you might be looped. Try it and find out? :)

Comment: Would I use json_encode?

Comment: I edited your question, so hopefully it's a little more clear what you're asking (and I believe I understood your intent well enough that it's still asking the same question).  But you don't want to use json_encode, or to encode it as JSON at all, because you'll lose all of the `phpexcel` methods that I assume are necessary to create the excel document you're looking for. As I said in my answer, a serialized PHP object has no business being stored in an HTML form under normal circumstances.

Comment: Yeah your edit is probably more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically what I do in these scenarios is one of the following:

1) Generate and save the information as a document at the same time as I generate the page to display to the user.  Then, when they want to download it, I link directly to the file I just created.  This is appropriate when it's a low volume page that maybe one person or a handful of people will be accessing once a day, and they have a high probability of downloading the file every time they use it.  **This is usually the scenario I find myself if when generating these sorts of documents**.  Just make sure you manage your documents so they don't pile up, probably by overwriting existing documents with the most recent document every time you generate it, or otherwise by deleting old documents.

2) When they click to download, just re-generate the data with the same queries.  This is appropriate if the queries are fast and the data doesn't change much, or it doesn't matter if the data that they download is slightly updated from the data they see on the page.

3) When generating the data for the page, save it to the user `$_SESSION`, which should (for most objects, at least) serialize it and unserialize it appropriately for future access.  If `PHPExcel` doesn't handle this well, you'll probably want to create your own class that inherits from `PHPExcel` and use [`__sleep()` and `__wakeup()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) to appropriately manage any details you need to make sure it serializes and unserializes appropriately.  Then when you make your call to download the data, you can use the data in memory just like you had just created it.  You may want to actively manage your user session to make sure it doesn't sit in there taking up a bunch of memory each time the user requests a page, if it's a fair amount of data.

The last option is probably the most "correct" approach, and is likely to be appropriate for most scenarios.  A serialized PHP object has no business being stored in an HTML form to be passed back to the server, at least not under any normal circumstances.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I guess I'll go with 1 or 2 since storing it on the sessions seems like such a hassle. The data isn't too bad anyway.

Comment: I would at least try to just save your object to the session without any other modification, and see if it works.  You've got at least some chance of it working "for free" that way.  If it doesn't, and one of the other two methods suits your application, then go with one of them.